# How to toggle dark theme for whole page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

I have managed to toggle dark theme and light theme at press of checkbox in html and flask. But how can i make the dark theme cover the whole page, not just some div elements? The margins are still light theme... CSS code below:

```
.container {
  display: flow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--color-secondary);
}
        .theme-light {
            --color-primary: #0060df;
            --color-secondary: #fbfbfe;
            --color-accent: #fd6f53;
            --font-color: #000000;
        }

        .theme-dark {
            --color-primary: #17ed90;
            --color-secondary: #2a2c2d;
            --color-accent: #12cdea;
            --font-color: #ffffff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
```

This is the present dark theme:
[image]

Comment: This looks as if it is the body background that is not changing. Have you tried creating a second light and dark theme that changes the body with it? You may also be able to add margin: 0 to the container but this may stretch the section to the edges instead of keeping them where they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body{
   background: var(--color-secondary);
}
.container {
   display: flow;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: var(--color-secondary);
}
    .theme-light {
        --color-primary: #0060df;
        --color-secondary: #fbfbfe;
        --color-accent: #fd6f53;
        --font-color: #000000;
    }

    .theme-dark {
        --color-primary: #17ed90;
        --color-secondary: #2a2c2d;
        --color-accent: #12cdea;
        --font-color: #ffffff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to design your page in dark theme, and in light theme, make the classes only different in dark, light and use javascript to replace dark with light in your classes or the opposite according to the checkbox.

```js
document.querySelector("#theme-switcher").onchange = function() {
  var self = this;
  document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(elem) {
    if(self.checked && elem.className.indexOf("light") !== -1) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace("light", "dark");
    }else if(!self.checked && elem.className.indexOf("dark") !== -1) {
      elem.className = elem.className.replace("dark", "light");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.light-text {
  color: black;
}
.dark-text {
  color: white;
}
.light-mode {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.dark-mode {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="light-mode">
  <input id="theme-switcher" type="checkbox">

  <p class="light-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus quam. Sed purus. Vivamus eros augue, venenatis a, pretium non, eleifend at, wisi. Fusce vestibulum. Vivamus dui. Nullam sed arcu eu eros pretium tincidunt. Fusce leo diam, pharetra nec, venenatis vitae, consequat sed, est. Aliquam id mi. Praesent ligula. Vivamus vehicula nulla vitae purus. Morbi mauris. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec a nisl. Vivamus mattis lacinia sapien.</p>

  <p class="light-text">Morbi commodo luctus sem. Morbi mattis ultricies lorem. Nunc semper urna eget wisi. Pellentesque pellentesque, pede at auctor porta, sem metus consectetuer eros, ut vestibulum leo lacus eu libero. Nullam libero mauris, feugiat a, lacinia et, tincidunt et, nunc. Nunc lorem.</p>

  <p class="light-text">Ut ligula mauris, ornare eget, consequat sed, porta nec, massa. Donec ligula. Phasellus turpis elit, porttitor nec, vestibulum at, hendrerit vel, sapien. Donec justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean ut magna. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean nunc. Maecenas vulputate lorem ac dolor. Ut sed sapien. Ut placerat.</p>

  <p class="light-text">In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce vitae mauris. Aliquam a mi at quam posuere venenatis. Proin auctor, lacus eu vestibulum venenatis, turpis turpis porta lectus, at tempus lorem dui id libero. Suspendisse elementum, nunc et viverra viverra, orci nunc molestie nunc, quis dignissim magna lorem vitae urna. Donec tortor. Morbi convallis rutrum justo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt.</p>

  <p class="light-text">Nunc hendrerit semper nibh. Maecenas malesuada, arcu a sodales ultricies, sem felis scelerisque arcu, sed tempor velit mauris ut elit. Sed ut libero eu wisi eleifend condimentum. Proin justo. Fusce fringilla. In magna. Donec ac sem eget risus fermentum blandit. Morbi tristique arcu id eros. Curabitur sem. Suspendisse a tellus. Quisque nisl erat, luctus in, dictum nec, euismod ut, odio.
  Sed turpis nulla, mollis ac, malesuada sit amet, mattis eu, mi. Praesent tempor, erat ac consequat volutpat, eros odio rutrum eros, eget blandit enim massa vel velit. Vestibulum vestibulum orci eu nulla. Pellentesque augue augue, suscipit eu, auctor nec, auctor id, tortor.</p>

  <p class="light-text">Phasellus id leo vel orci luctus convallis. Donec rhoncus rhoncus lorem. Phasellus cursus. Mauris orci. Donec vel lacus sit amet urna tristique ornare. Vivamus fermentum posuere lectus. Vestibulum mollis lobortis diam. Nam feugiat mauris sed erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed orci.</p>
</div>
```