# Is there a way to switch between light and dark mode using Javascript without creating additional classes?

Tags: javascript, css, darkmode

CSS provides a media query `prefers-color-scheme`

```
  @media(prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    border-color: white;
  }
```

I was wondering if I can set the value via JavaScript?  I don't want to add additional classes or do some sort of logic that would switch style sheets like [Switch between Light & Dark Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407737/switch-between-light-dark-mode) or adding additional classes to the elements like [How to toggle dark theme for whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162584/how-to-toggle-dark-theme-for-whole-page)

Something along the lines of

```
window.colorScheme = "dark";
```

The context I have is to use it in vue-styleguideist just limit it on the component.  Right now I add a "wrapper" object for each component.

Comment: what is the difference between adding a class to `body` or switching the color scheme?

Comment: I'm guessing OP wants a dark theme "for free" without writing the dark theme's CSS

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible and probably will never be. You have to add a custom implementation.

Comment: Quick and dirty dark theme: `document.body.style.filter = 'invert(100%)';`

Comment: @LilDevil not what I want, my dark theme is not just an inversion of colors.

Comment: @phuzi you are correct.

Comment: @Archimedes Trajano well then I'm confused. You say "my dark theme" but also " I don't want to add additional classes" - well then how else do you expect to define _your_ theme?

Comment: I found a somewhat usable way Microsoft Edge supports setting the preference on a per app basis.  So I can control it from there.  I wonder if there's a simple extension that can do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, for you, you're going to have to invest the time to come up with the styling for your dark theme. For a start how would something automatically decide what the background colour for the page should be? Should it be black? dark gray? or even another dark colour?